# Verifying the divergence theorem; What is this surface?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> 8. Verify the divergence theorem for the function $\textbf{V} = xy  \textbf{i} - y^2 \textbf{j} + z \textbf{k}$ and the surface enclosed by the three parts (i) $z = 0, s < 1, s^2 = x^2 + y^2$, (ii) $s = 1, 0 \le z \le 1$ and (iii) $z^2 = a^2 + (1 - a^2)s^2, 1 \le z \le a, a > 1$.

Normally questions like these wouldn't pose a problem for me. However, I am having trouble interpreting the surfaces being described. Hopefully someone can shed some light on this.

Comment: (i) open disc in $z=0$ plane; (ii) cylinder with unit radius and unit height; (iii) half of the ellipsoid (put $s^2$ term on the lhs and divide by $a^2$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume that $s^2 = x^2 + y^2$ applies to all three parts and that $a$ is a fixed constant greater than $1$.  Then (i) describes a disk in the $xy$-plane, (ii) describes a cylinder of height $1$ and radius $1$, and (iii) describes (part of) an ellipsoid.